YA trilogy where boys live on an island. They're unaware of the existence of women
I remember a trilogy of YA books I read as a kid (2010s), but I can't remember the name. Here are a few details, maybe they'll strike a chord with someone here.

Boys live and study in a school on an island

They don't know that there are women

They play a sport game where you fight and hold a ball with your teeth

The boys who grow up disappear

Later, a main character escapes and finds a tribe living on the island, they have a women healer.



Roughly when was it you were a kid? Do you remember any other details such as cover image(s), character name(s), etc.

2010s... I think the name of the boy was the name of the book... In the end they escape to the main land which is post apocalyptic

The Méto series by French author Yves Grevet, the first book of which was published in 2008. As far as I can see, none of the four books have been translated into English.
Summary of the first book from the publisher's website, most of the translation courtesy of DeepL:

Sixty-four boys, divided into four age groups (the Light Blues, the Dark Blues, the Violets and the Reds), spend four years cooped up in a large house with very rigid and meticulously defined rules, where sports - the astonishing game of Inche, played on all fours with the ball between the teeth... - and instruction - mainly in biology and agriculture - play a major role. Any misbehavior is severely punished by the "Caesars", enigmatic characters who appear when you least expect them, and always have an eye on everything. None of the children have any memory of their past, but they're all convinced that they're very lucky to be staying at the House, and live in fear of their beds "cracking" - the beds are extremely fragile. Because as soon as a Red exceeds the regulation size and breaks his bed, he leaves the House and is never seen again...

The titular Méto is indeed the main character.
I don't remember whether they actually don't know that women exist, but I remember all pages pertaining to human reproduction being stripped from their schoolbooks. Since animal reproduction was covered, I reckon some of the boys deduced there would have to be a female equivalent to their own male anatomy.
When the boys rebelled and eventually took control of "the House", one of the first subjects covered in the classes, by popular demand, was the one of female anatomy (the missing pages were found somewhere in the rulers' offices).


Found by memory, I had to read the first one for school and followed up with the others since, I think, the first one ended fairly abruptly.
